# How to set DataSet.DataTable as static

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, dataset, reportviewer

Do you see this photo
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BghAf.jpg)

I want to set this Tables as static DataTable

i can't use this information in another class

Finally

That it is all for Reporting viewer

Help me pleas

Comment: What do you mean "as static"?

Comment: i want to use it from many class 
every time when run my project  and binding this table from another class
 
i lost my information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay  Friends

i find the solution

we are can't set datatable in DataSet as static

But when use this dataset in another Form ( such as  in ReportViewer )

will create new dataset element in Form Look to this Photo

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6veoQ.jpg)

one Click on this DataSet and go to properties and set modifiers public

then everything will be fine when use this table  in any class

use this table and don't use table in photo question above

Comment: Because when use table in above question every time will be create new table 
and will lose your information every time

Answer (score -3):

```
public static System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
```

Comment: I can't binding this solution  with dataset